# Make a C++ program ask something many times

Tags: c++

Can someone help me? I want to make a program that asks me "Whats the first?", "Whats the second?", "Whats the third?" etc. I want it to ask me that as many times as I have told it. It is stored in the int noftimes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Get number of grades.
    int nofgrades = 7;
    cout << "How many grades do you want to calculate?\n";
    cin >> nofgrades;
    //Get grades.
    cout << "What's the " << (nofgrades - (nofgrades - 1)) << "st grade?\n";
    //Calculate average.

    //Display average.


    return 0;
}
```

I'm programming in C++. All help is appreciated.

Comment: You should get a good book.

Comment: Do you know what a loop is? If not, try to learn that and next time ask a more specific question.

Comment: you wanna ask "what's the 1st" or "what's the first?"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a topic that is covered in any good introductory book.

Comment: How about being a little less ambitious and asking `Please enter grade #n: ` instead? You can accomplish that using a simple loop.

Comment: You'll need some elaborate coding to convert `7654321` to `seven million six hundred fifty four thousand three hundred twenty first`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, by using for loop it's simple to do what you ask. Read a bit more about for loops and general programming principles. Look at [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/) subreddit sidebar for good resources.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Get number of grades.
    int nofgrades; // Why did you initialize it when you're going to override it anyway?
    cout << "How many grades do you want to calculate?\n";
    cin >> nofgrades;
    //Get grades.
    for (int i = 1; i <= nofgrades; ++i) {
        cout << "What's the " << i << "st grade?\n";
        //Load aditional grades... 
    }
    //Calculate average.

    //Display average.


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "What's the 2st grade?"

Comment: Ok, true, some additional logic is needed but for educational purposes for loop is important.

Comment: Thanks! It's what I wanted! :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to say that it's good practise to initialise variables. Is that so? Edit: added an ?.